# HTML5 CSS3 why wont my div tag with a class name move my margin left?

Tags: html, css

This is my css file and my html file, i made a div tag inside my header and gave it a class name of zebusoft-logo so then i call that in css with the .zebusoft-logo but when i use the margin-left: 400px; it doesnt move the logo at all. Why is this and how can i fix it?

**styles/main.css**

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}

header  {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:102px;
    background-color:#222;
    padding:20px;
}

footer {
    background: #222;
    width: 100%;
    height: 370px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}

.zebusoft-logo {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 400;
}
```

**mypage.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Joes Nose</title>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<header>
    <div class="zebusoft-logo"><img src="images/logo-3.png" alt=""></div>
</header>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I can add padding by saying this, padding: 0 0 0 400px; But i would still like to know why margins aren't working?

Comment: Did you try using `position: relative;` instead of `fixed` in the `zebusoft-logo` class?

Answer (score 3):

Simplified tests indicate this should work, provided you put the units (`px`) for your margin.

You have:

`margin-left: 400;`

You need:

`margin-left: 400px;`

Comment: I type too slow and cite too much! ;)

Comment: Citations are a good shout either way - I personally just tested it with/without units in a bare html file ;)

Comment: Ok, that was just a big goof on my part ); lol, but now i encounter another problem. i added a div tag to my body section of the html code the class for that tag was body-text inside the div tag is a h1 tag with text in it, but no text shows up between my header and footer does anyone know why?

Comment: Is your image overlapping your text? A `fixed` position element with `top: 0` will overlap text at the top of your document (unless it is a semi-transparent image)

Comment: Thats the header tho, i put the text in the body section the header isnt in the body

Comment: Plus i tried in the css doing top: 130px; from the top the move the div tag down with the text in it and still no show.

Comment: A `<header>` tag should appear in the body of your document. Any content for your `<html>` document appears in the `<body>` tags (incl. the header). A `fixed` element is fixed relative to the viewport (your browser) so it will likely overlap with any elements in the top of the doucment body.

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS...

```
.zebusoft-logo {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 400;
}
```

You set the margin-left to `400` but you don't specify what *unit* to use. You ***must*** specify the units unless the value is zero, so `padding: 0;` is OK but `margin-left: 400;` is illegal.
See the definition of dimensions in CSS3 Values and Units § [4.4 Numbers with Units: dimensions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#dimensions).

I assume you want pixels, so your margin must be set as `margin-left: 400px;`

Your html is also not structured correctly...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Joes Nose</title>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<header>
    <div class="zebusoft-logo"><img src="images/logo-3.png" alt=""></div>
</header>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

You are missing the `<head>` element which is where your `<title>` and your link to the stylesheet should be, and your `<header>` must be within the `<body>` of the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Joes Nose</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="zebusoft-logo"><img src="images/logo-3.png" alt=""></div>
    </header>

    <div>...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plus i tried in the css doing top: 130px; from the top the move the div tag down with the text in it and still no show.

Comment: I believe that is because your `<header>` is not inside your `<body>` tag, which it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to reformat your html and that will fix the problem.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Joes Nose</title>
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
    html, body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }






    header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 102px;
        background-color: #222;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    footer {
        background: #222;
        width: 100%;
        height: 370px;
        bottom: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .zebusoft-logo {
        padding: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: 400;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="zebusoft-logo"><img src="images/logo-3.png" alt=""></div>
</header>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume the OP has separate html and css files and it's just formatted poorly in the paste-job; that the CSS is actually in _styles/main.css_ which the html cites.

Comment: correct sorry im new to the site not sure how to use it yet